# Counting Problem, Correct Solution?

Tags: self-study, combinatorics

A committee of 5 people is to be selected from a group of ten. How many are there if among the group is a married couple which can only be selected together.

So there are ${10 \choose 5}$ committees in total. Now we have to count the number of committees that contain both. There are ${10 \choose 2}$ ways to choose the couple so the solution would be $\frac{{10 \choose 5}}{{10 \choose 2}}$ is that correct?

Comment: I do not understand your division. You might do better to count the committees with both members of the couple (and three other people) and the committees with neither member of the couple  (so five other people)

Comment: So there are 10C2 ways to choose the couple and then 8 * 7 * 6 to choose the rest. Then we have 8*7*6*5*4 ways to choose without the couple and 10C5 in total. Hence (10C2 * 8*7*6 * 8*7*6*5*4)/10C5. Is that correct?

Comment: There is exactly *one* way to choose the couple.  Either it is chosen or not.  When chosen, count the number of ways of choosing the remaining three committee members.  When not chosen, count the number of ways of choosing the remaining five members.  Sum the results (because they have no committees in common).

Comment: So if couple is chosen: 1 * 8 * 7 * 6  / 3!+ if couple is not chosen: 8C3 = 56 + 56 = 112. Is that correct then?